# How do a add scroll bar with fixed header

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I modify this CSS to apply a scroll bar with fixed header?

```css
#gradient-style {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    overflow: auto;
}

#gradient-style th {
    font-size: 12px;
}

#gradient-style td {
    height: 20px;
}
```

My table is like this:

```
<table  id="gradient-style" align="center">
```

Comment: You'll need to post the HTML that goes with this.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "fixed header". Do you mean you want the scrollbar on the table, but you want only the table content to be scrollable and the table header to stay fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about fixed table header with scrollable table content(table body).

Please check this example : http://jsfiddle.net/randeep161/n8zNq/